# What is the Purpose of /etc/init/udev-fallback-graphics.conf in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, graphics, upstart, udev

What is the purpose of the upstart configuration /etc/init/udev-fallback-graphics.conf (shown below) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

```
# fallback-graphics - take actions to initiate fallback graphics
#
# if we have cold plugged everything and not yet seen a valid graphics
# device,
# shove a fallback framebuffer into the mix and hope for the best.

description "load fallback graphics devices"

# We only want this job to happen once per boot, hence 'startup and ...'.
start on (startup and 
      (graphics-device-added PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
           or drm-device-added PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
           or stopped udevtrigger or container))

task

script
    if [ "$PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY" = "" ]; then
        modprobe -q -b vesafb
    fi
end script
```

I would think it would rarely be invoked, unless a video graphics driver is missing.  If a graphics driver is missing, there's still no guarantee that `modprobe -b -q vesafb` will succeed.  If it fails, the script exits with the return code from modprobe and /var/log/boot.log will contain a message similar to the following:

```
 * Starting load fallback graphics devices[74G[[31mfail[39;49m]
```

The message is not very informative.  The script code in the upstart configuration looks like a kludge to me.  I would rather see a specific warning or error message displayed if the return code from `modprobe` indicates failure, e.g.,

```
modprobe -q -b vesafb || echo "No suitable graphics driver found."
```